# Android: keep UI with constant size

Tags: android, user-interface

In my android application i have to design an UI. I have to distribute area of scrollview(70%) and relativelayout(30%) within a linearlayout(100%). But in my code it changes its area with the change of button in scrollview and consume the area of relativelayout. Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100"     
>
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lastLayout"
    android:layout_weight="70"        
    >        
    <LinearLayout   
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_add"
        android:background="@drawable/albumbackground"
        android:padding="10dp"
    >         
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/albumAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/albumremove"
        android:src="@drawable/add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/albumremove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
        android:src="@drawable/delete" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

when there few buttons then the UI shows like this
[image]

but when the no of button increase the UI shows like this
[image]

how can i keep the scrollview and relativelayout size constant? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_height="0dp"` on both children of `LinearLayout`.

Weights are to fill unused space. If your children have size of 0 unused space will be divided like you want it.

Comment: Have you set that on `ScrollView` and `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: yeah i set it to scrollview and relativelayout